# Sum of Products in boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

What is the minterm equivalent of A' + B'?

The options are
1)sigma(0,1)
2)sigma(0,1,2)
3)sigma(1,2)
4)sigma(1,2,3)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you show us what you've tried ?

Comment: I went through some youtube tutorials.....did not really understand it

Comment: Well Abhiram, I'm leaving some hints: $$A' + B' = A'(B+B') + B'(A+A') = A'B+A'B' + AB' + A'B' = A'B'+A'B+AB' $$ Can you find now?